# STL way to represent data structures that implies cross-referencing

Tags: c++, oop, stl, c++17, incomplete-type

Often I faced the following situation. (*Without loss of generality*: I use for the following example a simpliest possible case of two containers, but in an implementations of geometrical algorithms there are a plenty of them needed to describe an interconnected graphs data structures.)

I have a plenty values of two data types `A` and `B` which references to each other (not one-to-one generally), say, at first by means of (native) pointers or references. Both of them are emplaced into containers `using CA = std::container1< A >;` and `using CB = std::container2< B >;`. A result of some function is a pair of `CA` and `CB` instances. Having an element of `CA` instance I want to remove referenced element in `CB` instance and vice versa.

```
struct A;
struct B;

using CA = std::container1< A >;
using CB = std::container2< B >;
```

I want to define `A` and `B` as following:

```
struct A
{
    int payload;
    typename CB::iterator pb; // hard error here in general case of choosing `std:container2`
};

struct B
{
    double payload;
    typename CA::iterator pa;
};

// ...
PA a;
PB b;
// ...
assert(!a.empty());
assert(a.begin()->pb != b.end()); // and pb is not default-constructed
b.erase(a.begin()->pb);
```

[Live example.](https://ideone.com/nc5bjE)

But currently I can't declare `typename CB::iterator pb;` in general case, just only `B /*const*/ * pb;` or `B /*const*/ & pb;`, because type `B`, which is the part of `CB` declaration, is incomplete at point of using member `typedef iterator` of container `CB` into definition of aggregate `A`.

There is a proposal of a containers of an incomplete types, but it is not currently a part of the Standard.

For the current implementation of non-debug versions of containers in *libstdc++* and *libc++* the code above may be compiled fine by chance, but it is not mandatory at all. In case of success a definitions of iterators does not contain anything except pointers or references to the `value_type` for sure. But there is no requirement for that in the Standard.

As you can see in [live example](https://ideone.com/nc5bjE) there is hard error for `std::unordered_set`, due to its iterator requires `std::hash` of `value_type` to be complete type.

Double indirection proposed into comments may be not to good solution due to architecture (OOP) and performance reasons. At least it looks ugly to define `std::container3< B * >` along with `std::container2< B >` and track the validity of a resulting zoo of a different cross-referenced containers.

Iterators have pointer semantics by nature. And they shouldn't demand completeness of referenced type.

How to deal with the problem in `C++14` and previous?

Comment: This is a very confusing problem to follow.

Comment: @erip What the source of the problem to follow properly?

Comment: Maybe it's because I don't know what Voronoi actually is, but I don't see what the problem is? Does your code not compile?

Comment: @Orient, I suggest you remove the entire first part of your question, then create a compilable example along the lines of your ADDITIONAL update, and show the compiler error. The problem of containers that have references (in OOP sense, not C++ sense) to each other's members is an interesting one.

Comment: actually your second example [compiles without errors](https://ideone.com/Roj21f)

Comment: @tobi303 Try it for `deque`, `list`, `set`, `unordered_set`. For some of them it should give an error. For ideone's current compiler's stdlib impementation `unordered_set` gives an error. And no one other should mandatory compiles fine, I sure.

Comment: tried all of them, only with `unordered_set` i got an error, but no error when I used `using CA = std::unordered_set< A* >; using CB = std::unordered_set<B*>;`

Comment: @tobi303 I may accept double indirection as partial answer, but I don't like it for sure.

Comment: @tobi303 I have encountered an error on deque (clang OSX), at `sizeof` of
    `static const difference_type __block_size = sizeof(value_type) < 256 ? 4096 / sizeof(value_type) : 16;`

Comment: @user1887915 deque of objects or deque of pointers?

Comment: @tobi303 deque of objects

Comment: so unordered_set and deque are problematic, set, vector, list are OK. Interesting...

Comment: Are you free to change/choose the container type? If so, how about using two maps: map<A,B> one; map<B,A> two; ?

Comment: N4582 says incomplete types are only legal for `forward_list`, `list`, and `vector`; if any other containers work (e.g. `deque`, `set`, `unordered_set`), it is purely incidental and non-portable.

Comment: @denniskb I am not free to choose container type. There are time complexity reasons. One container should to allow me to erase element `O(1)` time in the middle of the container, another one should not invalidate the references during its growth etc. All choises are made carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your second example with `vector`, `list`, `deque`, `set` and `unordered_set`. Only for `unordered_set` I got a compiler error that I could fix by using container of pointers:

```
 using CA = std::unordered_set< A* >;
 using CB = std::unordered_set< B* >;
```

See [here](https://ideone.com/sekmwP) (Ideone.com C++14).

Comment: I think `std::unique_ptr<A>` instead of `A*` is better.

Comment: And, in most of the cases, needs to provide Hash (2nd) and KeyEqual (3rd) template argument to make it correct.

Comment: @user1887915 most of what cases? I was only refering to the example in the question. Whether it is better to use a `unique_ptr<A>` or some other smart pointer might depend on the actual use case

Answer (score 1):

An insane solution would be to store aligned storage and manually manage the object lifetime of the iterator, static asserting you made the storage the right size.

It is a real pain and quite unsafe (easy to make mistakes), but it works.

Use the size/alignment of boring container iterators.  Access iterator using free function via adl.

`std` tends to over require fully defined types.

A careful use of crtp and tags might let you automate the dangerous code, but tricky.

Answer (score -1):

In your live example, fundamentally what you have is: an `int` and a `double` with a 1:1 relationship, the ints are stored in a `vector<int>` and the doubles in a `unordered_set<double>`.

One path could be to simplify the problem e.g. would you be able to put data into an `unordered_map<double, int>`? Sometimes that might be true and will solve a lot of effort. Sometimes that might not be true e.g. you might need to sort data by the ints.

I think the path of using std 2 containers is riddled with difficulties of which your compilation error is just the tip of the iceberg e.g.:

- for a 1:1 relationship, when you add an entry you need to insert into two containers, so maybe you need to handle the case when you insert into one, but the other fails
- the iterators might get invalidated (e.g. if you have a iterator to a vector element and you sort the vector)
- the values in [unordered_]sets (and the [unordered_]keys in maps) are const (so you can't change them after you added them)

The other path could be: consider using something like boost bimap or multi_index. They take advantage of the fact that if say you want two node based structures (e.g. two sets) with a 1:1 relationship, then for an insert it only needs to make one allocation containing both nodes

Comment: `payload` is just an example. You can see through editions of the question and find, that initially the original question has a different formulation. There should be a plenty of geometrical structures connected with each other mutually.